# bootstrap 3.0 multiple textbox in horizontal form issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display three small text box elements within horizontal form group class. using code

```
<div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-lg-3 control-label input-sm">Date of Birth:</label>
           <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <input type="text" id="txt_month" name="txt_month" class="form-control input-sm"  placeholder="MM" required maxlength="2" data-validation-required-message="Month is required" >
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                   <input type="text" id="txt_day" name="txt_day" class="form-control input-sm"  placeholder="DD" required maxlength="2" data-validation-required-message="Day is required" >
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                   <input type="text" id="txt_year" name="txt_year" class="form-control input-sm"  placeholder="YY" required maxlength="4" data-validation-required-message="Year is required" >
                 </div>

              </div>

           <p class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
         </div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Is there a better approach to display multiple text boxes near to each other. Rest of elements in form display horizontally.

**Update#**

After using inline form class with lots of other modifications, i got proper result. here is updated code.

```
<div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-lg-3 control-label input-sm">Date of Birth:</label>
           <div class="col-lg-7">
              <div class="form-inline">
                      <div class="form-group ">
                         <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label class="sronly" for="txt_month">Enter Month</label> 
                        <input type="text" id="txt_month" name="txt_month" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:60px"  placeholder="MM" required maxlength="2" data-validation-required-message="Month is required" >
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                         <label class="sronly" for="txt_day">Enter Day</label> 
                         <input type="text" id="txt_day" name="txt_day" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:60px"  placeholder="DD" required maxlength="2" data-validation-required-message="Day is required" >
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <label class="sronly" for="txt_year">Enter Year</label> 
                          <input type="text" id="txt_year" name="txt_year" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:60px"  placeholder="YY" required maxlength="4" data-validation-required-message="Year is required" >
                        </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
           <p class="help-block"></p>
           </div>
         </div>
```

**Correct Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer really helped me work out my form with BS3.

However I wanted it to look like this:

[image: Creating inline forms with no label]

So, I amended the above and added the 'sr-only' class to the labels I wanted to hide (so screen-readers still pick them up), and changed the col sizes.

(NOTE: the OP uses 'sronly' class not the 'sr-only' class which doesn't work for me)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label ">City & County:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="sr-only" for="city">City</label> 
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control " placeholder="E.g. Manchester" >
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="sr-only" for="county">County</label> 
          <input type="text" id="county" name="county" class="form-control " placeholder="E.g. Lancashire" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes use [Inline Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). Check their documentation

Comment: Thanks, but using form inline class within horizontal form and other modifications fixed my issue. i posted working example too.